# Using $.post to load data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm currently coding my own blog type site, just for fun.
I didn't know any php/mysql/javascript at the beggining of this project, and I've learnt a ton, and so far the process of coding this has been more or less fluid, however, I have finally found myself stuck, with the problem of content loading in the main part of the site, which I guess is a bit more complex than the stuff I've been doing...

I want to use a triggered way of displaying more posts, by order of date, and I found a Jquery plugin called Jscroll; so far it does what it says it does, but I don't know how to use it along with some other method in order for it to load new content with every click on a certain link.

I guess this can be achieved by applying AJAX techniques, and I've been looking at the documentation on the $.post() function from Jquery, which, from what I understand, is able to send data to a target file so then you're able to retrieve that data with $_POST, for instance.

**Here's my code for the Jscroll plugin, with an explanation of the parameters...**

```
$('#postwrap').jscroll({
    autoTrigger: false, //False makes the content load only by a trigger (a link)
    loadingHtml: "<div><img src=/img/loading.gif><small> Loading...</small></div>",
    callback: Test, //Loads a function after the content is loaded (it doesn't actually work if I write it with the (), like Test()
});
```

**And... here's the Test function referenced by the callback setting in the code above**

```
  function Test(){
   $.post( "loadArticle.php", { test1: "a", test2: "b" } );
  }
```

So, in "loadArticle.php", I am trying to retrieve the values $.post sends, through $_POST['test'], but after the trigger loads the next set of contents, I do a var_dump of the variable sent, and I get NULL values. I know I'm "sending" nothing worthwhile, but if I actually manage to get something, then I'll procceed to whatever I come up with to actually retrieve database posts in an orderly manner.

I don't know if this can be done this way, if $.post() is even supposed to do what I think it does, if I am misunderstanding something, and if there is any other way...
I'd really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Can you open the 'Network' tab of your browser's developer tools and look at the response headers after you send the post request?

Comment: Well, I didn't know about that, that's awesome. I found it, and whenever I press the trigger, I can see a GET request and a POST request, the POST request does have the declared parameters (test1 and test2, in this case)... I think that maybe I get NULL values because the POST request is being sent AFTER loadarticle.php loads, and so it doesn't have a chance to retrieve the data and display it? But in that case... wouldn't the data be stored for the second time it loads, and then it shouldn't display NULL? (but it does)

Comment: Try putting echo $_POST['test1']; in the loadarticle.php file, and then look at the Response tab inside the Network tab. It should output something.

Comment: Nevermind, it is outputting something in the response tab, it's just that it doesn't show...

Comment: What I'm wondering is how did you get those `null` values printed? since the request is *async* and without echoing back. FYI, each requests are processed separately and don't have any knowledge of other requests.

Comment: The null values are printed as a result of var_dump($_POST['test1']);, which I called in loadArticle.php, and it prints on the main site because I'm using loadArticle.php as a template that Jscroll uses to load another div to display as another post (and I'm trying to pass a "counter" to it, so I can display posts accordingly), if that makes any sense... ha. I guess it isn't exactly the same as echoing the variable, since when I echo it, the variable sent prints on the Response tab, but not on the "final" main site, I guess that is because of the reasons you mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the the element loaded in your container div each time you call your AJAX function.. Do something like this..

```
var loader = {};

    loader.content = function(element){
        var contentCount = $(element).children().length;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://yoursite.com/loadcontent.php',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            data:{
                offset:contentCount
            }
            success:function(data){
                var htmlString = '<div class="samplechild"><h4>'+data.title+'</h4><p>'+data.post+'</p></div>';
                $(element).append(htmlString);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#postwrap').jscroll({
        autoTrigger: false, //False makes the content load only by a trigger (a link)
        loadingHtml: "<div><img src=/img/loading.gif><small> Loading...</small></div>",
        callback: loader.content('.container'), //Loads a function after the content is loaded (it doesn't actually work if I write it with the (), like Test()
    });
```

**ANOTHER OPTION FOR INFINITE SCROLL**

```
var loader = {};

    loader.content = function(element){
        var contentCount = $(element).children().length;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://yoursite.com/loadcontent.php',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            data:{
                offset:contentCount
            }
            success:function(data){
                var htmlString = '<div class="samplechild"><h4>'+data.title+'</h4><p>'+data.post+'</p></div>';
                $(element).append(htmlString);
                $(element).animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).on('click','.button-link',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        loader.content('.containerDiv');
    });
```

Comment: Well, I tried this, and something isn't working for me... I replaced .container with .post, which is the name of the div that contains each article... Maybe an issue with the Jscroll plugin?

Comment: Aside from jscroll you can also customize your own infinite scroll fn please see my post's updates

Comment: Thank you! This works... I must admit that I didn't understand the code completely, and that's why it took me a while to test it, but it works (which is simply a triggered "display more"). I of course am going to make some modifications to it for my particular situation. Just some notes, however: I **think** that you are **missing** a `;` for closing the $.ajax() call, and I replaced the last bit of the code: `$(document).on();` for `$('#link').click();`... I think it is equivalent. Thank you again.